# Downloading a pdf using R generates corrupted file

Tags: r, pdf

I'd like to download the pdf file from this website using R. The file is being downloaded but I can't open it as it says the pdf is corrupted. Here is my code:

```
url <- "https://www.bchousing.org/research-centre/housing-data/new-homes-data"
download.file(url, 'New Homes Registry Report - June 2020.pdf', mode="wb")
```

Can you please let me know the issue?

Comment: That link is to an HTML page, not to a pdf file. Perhaps you should try to use the [`rvest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/index.html) package to try to scrate the filename from the content?

Comment: Do you know how I can fix the code then?

Comment: Try downloading something which is a pdf, like `https://www.bchousing.org/publication/New-Homes-Registry-Report-January-2020.pdf`.

Comment: I you just need *this* data *this* time, then it's much faster to download outside of R and figure out what to do with the files after that. If you need to automate this process, though, then scraping in this case it most likely done well with `rvest`. If that doesn't work, there are other methods, but none of them are as easy as `rvest`.

Comment: Yes, the reason that I want to automate the process is that, I have to extract the latest data from table 3 each month. I used to manually open the latest pdf and read the number in table 3 but I was thinking that this process can be automated using R. I am thinking to follow these steps using R: 1- Download the latest monthly pdf file 2- Extract the data from table 3 3- Get the latest number (e.g., June 2020). I'm now stuck in step #1.

Comment: Yes. Look at `rvest`.

Comment: Thanks, using rvest I could list the pdf files: